# Difficulty in getting mp3 to work in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to get Paperclip to accept an mp3 file.  I was able to get this to work in a Rails 2 app, but am having difficulty in Rails 3.  I can get the file to show up in my assets directory, but I continue to get the missing.png listed instead of the appropriate file in the show action.

Here is my model code...

> has_attached_file :sermonfile,
>                         :url => "/assets/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
>                         :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:class/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"
>        attr_accessor :sermonfile_file_name   attr_accessor
>   :sermonfile_content_type
>   attr_accessor :sermonfile_file_size
>   attr_accessor :sermonfile_updated_at

Here is the form view...

> <%= form_for @sermon, :html =>
>   {:multipart => true} do |f| %>   <% if
>   @sermon.errors.any? %>
>
> ### <%= pluralize(@sermon.errors.count,
>   "error") %> prohibited this sermon
>   from being saved:
>
> ```
>   <ul>
>   <% @sermon.errors.full_messages.each do
> ```
>
> |msg| %>
>
> <%= msg %>
>
> <% end %>
>         
>          <% end %>
>
> <%= f.label :title %>
>       <%= f.text_field :title %>      
>       <%= f.label :permalink %>
>       <%= f.text_field :permalink %>      
>       <%= f.label :speaker %>
>       <%= f.text_field :speaker %>      
>       <%= f.label :date %>
>       <%= f.date_select :date %>      
>       <%= f.label :series %>
>       <%= f.text_field :series %>      
>       <%= f.label :book %>
>       <%= f.text_field :book %>      
>       <%= f.label :passage %>
>       <%= f.text_field :passage %>      
>       <%= f.label :notes %>
>       <%= f.text_area :notes, :class => "mceEditor" %>          <%= f.file_field
>   :sermonfile %>      
>       <%= f.submit %>    <% end %>

This is what I am using to render the file in the show view...

> <%= link_to @sermon.sermonfile.url %>

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please format this properly? specially the part in bold

Answer (score 1):

Your `:url` & `:path` have their `:id` & `:style` mixed up. They should be the same: `:id/:style`

```
has_attached_file :sermonfile, 
  :url => "/assets/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```